# "IF" code is not working inside for each?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, sockets, hashtable

so im learning to use socket and thread things in the networking software. so far, the software (which is not created by me) is able to chat in multiple group, but i'm tasked to allow user to code whisper feature. However, im stuck in the coding area, which im sure will work if the "if" function work inside "for each" function, anyhow here is my code mainly

```
Private clientCollection As New Hashtable()
Private usernameCollection As New Hashtable()

clientCollection.Add(clientID, CData)
usernameCollection.Add(clientID, username)
```

oh and before i forgot, the code above and below is on the server form page

on the client side, i write the code:
    writer.write("PMG" & vbnewline & txtReceiverUsername & Message)

then next is the checking part on the server reading the message:

```
ElseIf message.Substring(0, 3) = "PMG" Then
                    'filter the message, check who to send to
                    Dim newMessage As String = message.Substring(3)
                    Dim messagearray As String() = newMessage.Split(vbNewLine)
                    Dim receiver As String = messagearray(1)
                    '0 = "", 1 = receiver, 2 = message
```

as i write before, clientcollection contain (clientID , connection data*) and usernamecollection contain (clientID, username). In my case, i only have the username data, and i need to trace it until the *connection data* on clientcollection hash table.

```
                    'find realid from usernamecollection, then loop clientcollection
                    Dim clientKey As String = 0

                    For Each de As DictionaryEntry In usernameCollection
                        '''''
                        'this if part Is Not working
                        If de.Value Is receiver Then
                            clientKey = de.Key
                        End If
                        '''''
                    Next de

                    'match objKey with clientcollection key
                    For Each dec As DictionaryEntry In clientCollection
                        If dec.Key = clientKey Then
                            Dim clients As ClientData = dec.Value
                            If clients.structSocket.Connected Then
                                clients.structWriter.Write("PMG" & messagearray(2))
                            End If
                        End If
                    Next dec
End If
```

so, how do i know that the if part is the wrong one? simply i tried these code before the "next de" code

```
For Each client As ClientData In clientCollection.Values
          If client.structSocket.Connected Then
               client.structWriter.Write("PMG" & "receiver:" & messagearray(1))
               client.structWriter.Write("PMG" & "loop username: " & de.Value)
               client.structWriter.Write("PMG" & "loop key: " & de.Key)
               client.structWriter.Write("PMG" & "receiver key:" & clientKey)
          End If
Next
```

the code allow me to check the de.key and de.value. they were correct, however the only thing that did not work is the code inside the "if" area.

Can anyone suggest other code maybe beside "if de.key = receiver"? I've also tried using the if de.key.equal(receiver) and it did not work too

Comment: `Is` checks if 2 objects are the same reference.  since the code is working with 2 different collections it seems unlikely.  You'd have to compare some of the data in each object to see if they refer to the same person.  It is hard to say without knowing what the `receiver` is.  But do turn on Option Strict

Comment: What is the value of `receiver` and what is the value of `de.Value`?  Have you tried `If de.Value = receiver Then`?  Assuming those values are equal (including same case) then execution should enter the If block.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway receiver contain username of the target message. de.value contains username list in the hashtable, de.key contain clientID, which client got when they got connected. Also, i have try using using that if de.value = receiver, but still nothing happen inside the if. i also try to put into another variable like if variable a = de.value, but still nope.

Comment: @Plutonix receiver is a target username of message which i got from splitting the message from binary reader. i did try to check by using the binary writer to display de.value, de.key, receiver and clientKey. the output display is correct, but the client key didn't get anything. example i am sending to user B, so receiver = "B", and i would check if de.value = "B", then clientKey would get the de.key, which is 2 for example. when it comes to if function, it failed to transfer the de.key into client variable, causing the clientKey still 0 instead of 2. umm how do i turn on the Option Strict?